# VSCode Snippet remove rest of tabstop placeholders?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way when you use a snippet, and the placeholder tabstops come up, to remove the rest of the tabstops once you don't need any more? Basically, for functions or commands that you only need to specify a few parameters and not every param?

For example is this AHK command, I can tabstop to the first two palceholders but I don't need any others? I could use hotkey remove everything to the right but then it'll also remove the ")". So I'm just wondering if I'm missing a hotkey or feature to just remove rest of placeholders.

[image]

Comment: and what are you going to do with the `,` that are left after filling the tabs with nothing

Comment: with [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) you can create a command that selects up to the `)`, With Multi-Command you can group it with an `Exit Snippet (Esc)` and `Delete Selection`, bind this combi command to a key

Comment: ty for the suggestion which I think will work great if there is no native way to achieve this. I'm happy with this method.

As for the commas, I can delete the ones that have default values if left blank. I'll prob add that to the multicommand function.